# Schedule Rscript in a server

Tags: r, jobs

Currently, I am scheduling a daily bat from my laptop with TaskScheduler on windows and I would like to do it automatically in a server. Actually, the situation is:

1. I read some SQLite DB that I have stored in local.
2. Once I read them I do a webscraping based on some information.
3. I store this new information in the DB mentioned above.
   I've read that is possible do it with Amazon EC2 (REF: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/), but it doesn't mention anything related with SQLite local db.

Could you give me some recommendations about how to manage and which tool could be the best approach (Azure, AWS, Google Bigquery)

Comment: Why do you need Rstudio for that? you can use the same R script (with all you commands) you feed to the bat file and have `crontab` (if linux) to schedule when to run it. Something on the line of `0 12 * * * /path/to/your/R/bin/Rscript /home/username/myScript.R` .

Comment: Yes, all you need is a `crontab` entry. Thousands of other answers here on the site showing how to use `cron` and its `crontab` file. I have (public facing) cron jobs that have been running since the mid-2000s, the CRANBerries service is one, and it also uses SQLite for storing state.  No magic: just set up a script you can call, and call it from `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Cloud Run task to do this. Then schedule it using cloud scheduler.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler

You can find samples how to build a cloud run task in the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs

To write to big query, you can use the bigquery api client libraries: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries